# VS2012: Unable to attach to process but only for aspx pages and code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I'm experiencing something very weird.
I was able for a long time to attach to process to my published web site.
Out of the blue, I cannot anymore.
My breakpoints are not hit. What is very strange is that this happens only for "pages" (aspx and aspx.cs files). The referenced dll/libraries are ok, I can debug them!

I would expect the opposite.

Any suggestion?

Thanks,
Roberto

Comment: Have you tried restarting the services or restart the IIS?

Comment: @Deepak. I restarted IIS. Which other services are you talking about?

Comment: Do you have any other services linked to your project which needs to run. In order to execute the project?